# Python OOP error calling function within function

Tags: python, oop

I just started learning OOP and was trying to create a class
but apperently i am not able to call the fuction within function

```
class WordPic:
    
    def __init__(self,filename,outputname):
        self.skipped = ["was","in","the","have","think","these","we","as"]
        self.filename = filename
        self.outputname = outputname
        self.txt_freq = {}
    
    def get_frequancy(self):
        
        with open (self.file_location,"r") as f:
            lines = f.read().lower()
        splited_lines = lines.split()
        for line in splited_lines:
            if line not in self.skipped and line.isalpha():
                line = line[0].upper() + line[1:]
                if line not in self.txt_freq:
                    self.txt_freq[line] = 1
                else:
                    self.txt_freq[line] += 1
        return self.txt_freq

    def create_pic(self):
        cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud(background_color="white")
        cloud.generate_from_frequencies(self.txt_freq)
        cloud.to_file("{}.jpg".format(self.outputname))
    
    def create(self):
        get_frequancy(self)
        create_pic(self)
        print("created")


wc = WordPic("try.txt","done")
wc.create()
```

the error that i encounter is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [190], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 wc= WordPic("try.txt","done")
----> 2 wc.create()

Input In [188], in WordPic.create(self)
     28 def create(self):
---> 29     get_frequancy(self)
     30     create_pic(self)
     31     print("created")

NameError: name 'get_frequancy' is not defined
```

i am not able to find my way around if anyone can help. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_frequancy` is not a nonlocal variable; it's a class attribute. It has to be accessed as such. (The same goes for `create_pic`.)

```
def create(self):
    self.get_frequancy()
    self.create_pic()
    print("created")
```

(While `WordPic.get_frequancy(self)` would be sufficient in the example shown, calling instance methods like this runs into problems once you start taking inheritance into account.)

Comment: I guess you could also mention the typo (in case it's of interest)

Comment: @rv.kvetch It's not, in context. It may be misspelled, but it's misspelled consistently.